# Internet wifi works, but don'know the name of the device

Tags: networking, drivers, virtualbox

On my computer I installed windows: through virtualbox I installed ubuntu. I have a network adapter tp-link tl-wdn4800 and internet on ubuntu works perfectly.

The only problem is that I can not know the name of the device because when I type

```
sudo iwlist scan
```

the result is

```
eth0 Interface     does not support scanning.
the Interface      does not support scanning.
```

Where is the WiFi device?

Comment: VirtualBox most likely created a vitual Ethernet adapter, and it is acting like a NAT router for your VM.  What exactly is going on depends on how you installed things.  It is doubtful it is doing direct to the wireless adapter.  `/sbin/ifconfig` should list the network adapters your Linux VM knows about

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `iwlist scan` command as you expected on your Ubuntu VM (*i.e Virtual Machine*) because there isn't any wireless interface. Ubuntu VM is connected to internet through a virtual ethernet adapter created by Virtual Box.

In default configuration, VirtualBox put your VM in a different network and apply *NAT* (Network Address Translation) between VM and your host operative system.

So, even if your computer is connected via wireless to your router, from the point of view of Ubuntu VM it seems that it is connected to a router (in this case simulated by VirtualBox networking engine) through cable.

More information on https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the device from menus:

Machine > Settings > Networks

There you will be able to see your wireless interface listed in text field 'Name'.